# Typescript set default HTML Select

Tags: typescript, html-select

I have an html select that is built by typescript code and looks as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
  <select class="form-select selectFilter"  [selected]="sectorSelect" (change)="refreshSelect($event, 'sector')">
    <option *ngFor="let currentData of filterSector"  [value]="currentData">{{currentData}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have a reset button that looks like this

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 text-left">
   <button (click)="resetSelect($event, 'Reset')" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reset Filter</button>
</div>
```

My typescript method looks like this

```
resetSelect(e, mode) {
   
   if (mode === "Reset") {
      this.sectorSelect = "";        
   }
}
```

The issue I have is when I click the reset button, the select does not reset to the first option. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a "" value in currentData?

Comment: Good question, yes I do